# Android: headphone button to start/stop a stopwatch

Tags: android, button

I want to use the headphone button to start/stop a stopwatch.
Could anybody give me some hint (code, links, etc) to do that?
My problem is how to get the button event.
I'm absolutely begginer in android programming...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you could provide the source code.

To listen the events on Button you have to set a OnClickListener to it. For example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private Button button;
private boolean isStopWatchRunning=false;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(this);


}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    toggle();
}

private void toggle() {
    if(isStopWatchRunning){
        //Stop StopWatch
    }else{
        //Start StopWatch
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Prince, thanks for your time. My question, however, concerned the event of the headphone button, not a regular one.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`MediaButtonReceiver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaButtonReceiver.html) to receive the headphone button click. This works together with [`MediaSessionCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat.html). You need to register a service and override `onStartCommand()`

```
private MediaSessionCompat mMediaSessionCompat = ...;
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    MediaButtonReceiver.handleIntent(mMediaSessionCompat, intent);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

The [`MediaSessionCompat.Callback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat.Callback.html) you have to provide as well, has methods `onPause()`, `onStart()` and `onStop()` you can use for your implementation.

But you have to consider your use-case, since you loose control over your media with this. Instead you could also have a look into the [`MEDIA_BUTTON`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON) action and implement your behavior yourself.

Comment: Hi @tynn, thanks for your help. I've already seen those things at developer.android.com but unfortunately I don't have enough programming knowledge to make the code. I was looking for an example with the "key pressed" event ready to add the rest of the code.